# How to limit the amount of some value being copied.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a javascript that enables my users to set a value lets say '0.6' and with setting this value they can copy it to the class id I specify in my javascript. The problem is I would like to figure out a way to limit this so lets say they copy the value but only want it to paste into the first 5 text fields how can I can I set a limit on how many times the value gets pasted, I am confused on how to accomplish this because the class id I have could have any amount of text fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my JavaScript with the copy function

```
  $('.val_class').click(function() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to copy this value to each sample?.");
    var text = $('.val_box').val();
     if (r == true) {
       $('.reading_class').val(text);
     } else {

    }
  });
```

Here is my view.

```
%th
  %h2 Set a value to be copied to each sample.
  %br
  %tbody
    %td
      .js
      %li Reading One
      %br
      =f.text_field :valc, :id => 'valc', :class => 'val_box', :hint => "You can set a value in this text box that will be copied to all of the samples, by pressing copy value button."
      .control-group
        .controls
          %button{:type => "button", :class => 'val_class', :id => "val_class"}Copy this value to all samples(Reading One)


-@samples.each do |sample|

 =number_field_tag "dimension[samples][#{sample.id}][value1]", sample.value_for_dim(@dimension, index+1), :id => 'reading', :class => 'reading_class', :step => "0.000001"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a selector `$('.my_class')` and want to take only first `5` of them, simply do:

```
$('.my_class').slice(0, 5).val(text)
```

More info on `.slice()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)